Learning category theory from Lean formalization?
I am trying to learn basic category theory using Lean 4. I don't have prior coursework on it. And I wonder whether this is feasible and if there is a good tutorial for this.
My main goal is to be able to understand some of the references to concepts in category theory in Mathematics in Lean. For example, generalized element, university properties for various things. So, I am not looking to learn the whole of category theory. Just the basics to understand the language of mathematics nowadays.
I am more interested in learning the mathematical content in category theory rather than the lean language. Hopefully, this will serve as complement or extension of Mathematics in Lean.
Is there such a tutorial/online course for category theory in lean?

So you want to learn category theory and category theory in Lean’s mathlib at the same time? Why? I don’t think formal theorem provers are yet a good way to learn most mathematical subjects.  Especially since you are interested in the mathematical content of category theory, why not just find a good book on the subject?

@JasonRute Thanks for the feedback. I tried to read books. They have nice diagrams and figures. But they often start with examples from very different math branches that I know nothing about. I remember reading Category theory for the working mathematician, and stopped at initial examples about manifolds etc. This makes me wonder if lean is a better route. Everything is at least defined/encoded in a traceable format.

Category theory in mathlib is very beginner-unfriendly, because concepts are usually defined in a much more abstract way than the way you would typically see them in category theory introduction courses. This avoids a lot of repetition (because you only have to prove things once, in their most general form), but also means that to understand something out of Mathlib's definitions, you have to understand the most general form to begin with.

I recommend learning category theory from humans, and if those are not avaiable then from books. It is a feature of category theory that it draws examples from a wide range of mathematics, which is why we don't teach it in kindergarten, or in most undergraduate programmes.
Anyhow, I can recommend two books for beginners:

F. William Lawevere, Stephen H. Schanuel: Conceptual mathematics, Cambridge University Press, 2009

Steve Awodey: Category theory, Oxford University Press, 2006


As a PhD student I tried to learn category theory from MacLane's book and that did not work at all. The title is quite accurate, one already has to be a (professional) working mathematician to appreciate the book.
Once you understand some piece of category theory, it might be fun to go and look at how it is done in Lean.
